# Office/Word Add-in Uploading File to MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, office-js, office-addins

I am building an add-in for Word, with the goal of being able to save the open Word document to our MVC web application. I have followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/get-the-whole-document-from-an-add-in-for-word) and am sending the slices like this:

```
function sendSlice(slice, state) {
    var data = slice.data;

    if (data) {
        var fileData = myEncodeBase64(data);       
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {

                updateStatus("Sent " + slice.size + " bytes.");
                state.counter++;

                if (state.counter < state.sliceCount) {
                    getSlice(state);
                }
                else {
                    closeFile(state);
                }
            }
        }
        request.open("POST", "http://localhost:44379/api/officeupload/1");
        request.setRequestHeader("Slice-Number", slice.index);
        request.setRequestHeader("Total-Slices", state.sliceCount);
        request.setRequestHeader("FileId", "abc29572-8eca-473d-80de-8b87d64e06a0");
        request.setRequestHeader("FileName", "file.docx");

        request.send(fileData);
    }
}
```

And then receiving the slices like this:

```
    public void Post()
    {
        if (Files == null) Files = new Dictionary<Guid, Dictionary<int, byte[]>>();

        var slice = int.Parse(Request.Headers.GetValues("Slice-Number").First());
        var numSlices = int.Parse(Request.Headers.GetValues("Total-Slices").First());
        var filename = Request.Headers.GetValues("FileName").First();
        var fileId = Guid.Parse(Request.Headers.GetValues("FileId").First());

        var content = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        if (!Files.ContainsKey(fileId)) Files[fileId] = new Dictionary<int, byte[]>();
        Files[fileId][slice] = Convert.FromBase64String(content);

        if (Files[fileId].Keys.Count == numSlices)
        {
            byte[] array = Combine(Files[fileId].OrderBy(x => x.Key).Select(x => x.Value).ToArray());

            System.IO.FileStream writeFileStream = new System.IO.FileStream("c:\\temp\\test.docx", System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
            writeFileStream.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
            writeFileStream.Close();

            Files.Remove(fileId);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the file that is produced by the controller is unreadable in Word. I have tested with a word document with "Test123" as the entire contents of the document, and when the file is saved through word it is 13kb, but when sent to the web app and saved from there the file is 41kb.

My assumption is that the I am missing something either with the encoding or decoding, since I am only sending a single slice so there shouldn't be an issue with recombining them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an Excel snippet in [Script Lab](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104380862?src=office&tab=Overview) that produces the base64 encoded file which you can paste into an online decoder like www.base64decode.org. The APIs are the same as in Word. This can help you isolate the encoding code. After you install Script Lab, open the **Samples** tab, scroll to the **Document** section. It's the **Get file (using slicing)** snippet.